# Why my 2d array of int segfault with malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, int, malloc

This code doesn't segfault
I've try to "debug" it so I know when it segfault but don't understand why

```
range(int **range, int min, int max)   //prototype
*range = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (max - min));
if (*range == NULL)
    return (0);
while (min < max)
{
    range[0][z] = min; //Doesn't segfault
    printf("%d\n",range[0][z]);
    min++;
    z++;
}
```

This one does

```
range(int **range, int min, int max)//prototype
*range = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (max - min));
if (*range == NULL)
    return (0);
while (min < max)
{
    *range[z] = min;//Segfault Here
    printf("%d\n",range[0][z]);
    min++;
    z++;
}
```

Thanks for you help ;)

Comment: Where/how is `z` declared?  How is it initialized/assigned?  Note: `range` is not a 2D array, but a pointer to a pointer of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

If your array has sizes, say, A and B, in your first code fragment, the variable `z` works with increases of 1, while in the second it works with increases of A and gets the 0th element of each.

But since `z` is supposed to count the total elements it, of course, overflows.